# Enable English speech recognition on non-english Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, language, speech-to-text

It seems that non only that Microsoft didn't achieve to create speech recognition for any minor anguage, but they also intentionaly removed option to control your PC with English commands.
So is there some trick how to add English speech recognition to Czech version of Windows? Searches for external software solutions led only to commercial applications which is a luxury I cannot afford.

Comment: Speech Recognition is not supported on your version of Windows 7.  Since you cannot (legally ) installed language packs it also complicates things.  You would need to change the language of Windows in order to use speech recognition.

Comment: Well yeah, I realised is not *currently* supported. If it was supported, I wouldn't post here in the first place. My question is, whether I can **make it supported**.

Comment: Like I said you would need to change the language of Windows installation to English in order to add English speech recognition.

Comment: This means buying another windows?

Comment: You could simple install the English version of Windows 7 your license allows for this.  It just does not allow for multiple language packs.